# Replace local empty repository with one from GitHub

Tags: git

How to replace my local empty repository with files from my GitHub repository.

I have just created an account on a server for running a nodejs app. When I follow the setup instructions, they result in a local empty repository. But rather than edit the blank repository, I want to use the files that are in my GitHub repository. How do I replace them?

e.g. server setup instructions say to:

```
git clone https://server/empty.git coolapp
```

then make changes and push the changes back to the server.

Setup instructions https://docs.cloudno.de/quick-start-guide

Note: I'm sure this question has been posted before, but can't find it any more.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) is one way, indeed. What doesn't work?

Comment: edited question

Answer (score 1):

Make new directory:

```
mkdir directory_name
```

Change to your directory

```
cd directory_name
```

Clone the github repo:

```
git clone https://server/empty.git
```

Copy desired files from repo to location of your desire (other repo?):

```
 cp src_dirc destination_dir
```

Comment: am sure that would work - but not sure how I could then push any changes back to GitHub.

Comment: add remote to your own repo:
`code`git remote add githubrepo repo_path `code`

push changes
`code`git push githubrepo master `code`

Answer (score 0):

open terminal inside the folder and then do

```
git init 
git remote add origin "your repository path without quotes"
git pull origin master
```

then you can commit and push from the local folder